# Magento - How to allow certain tags (iframe, embed) in Magento's CMS editor?

Tags: magento-1.9

**Problem**: In cms page it's not possible to write any tag?. like

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_jHpnb-QmTA" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

If you click **show/hide Editor** button this content converted to

```
& lt;iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_jHpnb-QmTA" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe & gt;
```

I have tried according to their(tiny_mce) documentation. Also [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163518/magento-how-to-allow-certain-tags-iframe-embed-in-magentos-cms-editor). But no luck in **Magento 1.9.3.2**.

Any idea why it's not working?

Comment: Hi @sohel rana can you help me on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/296960/how-to-fetch-post-method-xml-data-in-magento2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This solution still working fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163518/magento-how-to-allow-certain-tags-iframe-embed-in-magentos-cms-editor). I tested in Magento 1.9.3.2. But here all answer are encourage modify core file. I just show here how you can do exact same thing in magento way.

So add following xml code into your handle. This is the overwrite tinyMce setup.

yourvendor/tiny-mce-setup.js

Now you need to create **magentorootfolder/js/yourvendor/tiny-mce-setup.js** file

```
if(window.tinyMceWysiwygSetup) {
    tinyMceWysiwygSetup.prototype.originalGetSettings = tinyMceWysiwygSetup.prototype.getSettings;
    tinyMceWysiwygSetup.prototype.getSettings = function(mode) {
        var settings = this.originalGetSettings(mode);
        settings.extended_valid_elements = 'iframe[src|style|width|height|scrolling|marginwidth|marginheight|frameborder|allowTransparency],img[class|src|border=0|alt|title|hspace|vspace|width|height|align|onmouseover|onmouseout|name]';
        return settings;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following thread can help you.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163518/magento-how-to-allow-certain-tags-iframe-embed-in-magentos-cms-editor

In that, customization is mentioned to achieve this.

Comment: It's not working for me. Did you tried or working for you this solution? And I already mention in my question.

Comment: Try clearing cache and hard reload in browser